# Why is my shape not extruding after I converted my vertices to a mesh?

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I created a custom shape by starting with a single vertex and then extruding it. I converted this to a mesh. However when I extrude this shape, nothing really happens. It sorts of duplicates the face, as you can see in the picture below.

What is happening? How can I extrude my shape?

Here is the file if necessary: [image]

[image]

Comment: You need to merge by distance because you have overlapping vertices, then it works, I don't know why it messes up the extrusion though

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you!